# Non working negated boolean in knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

The markup below fails, but I can´t figure out why as the positive version (without the exclamation mark works fine. Probably very silly but i had to ask. :)

```
<div data-bind="visible: ! $root.showMe">

where (in ViewModel):

self.showMe = ko.observable(false);
```

Comment: Please stop doing that much logic in the view, plus visible == not showMe is very strange. showMe is actually a bad name for a variable on a model. Thats a view term. Instead call it valid, invalid etc or what the business rule is

Comment: I appreciate your input. "showMe" is an example.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the classic! $root.showMe is a function. Negating a function causes nonsense, thus it does not work. However de-refering the function with it´s value works.

The valid markup is:

```
<div data-bind="visible: ! $root.showMe()">
```

Comment: Totally forgot about that. Deleted my answer as it wasn't adding anything useful. BTW: You can mark your on answer if you want, it's perfectly valid